# Add more than 2 profile in Civicrm contribution page

Tags: civicrm

I'm using civicrm contribution page to create a membership renewal page. But in the "Profile" tab, I'm only able to add  two profile, one in top of the page, one in bottom of the page.

Is there any way I can add in more than two profiles in the page? Just like in event page, I can add 7 profile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way of doing this through the user interface.

An alternative approach would be to use a Drupal webform integrated with CiviCRM. You'll need the Webform module, the webform_civicrm integration module, and various dependencies.

Depending on the payment processor you are using to process the membership payment, if indeed you are using any, you can then build a form that will include all the CiviCRM fields you need without needing to create profiles.

If you are using a payment processor and accepting online payments for you memberships, IPN-based processors, such as Paypal standard, aren't supported by this approach, but you can get around that by having the user taken from the webform through to a basic CiviCRM contribution page and they can make their payment there.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be to manipulate the page via JavaScript inserted in the content fields to arrange the fields as required. I admit though it's not very elegant and somewhat hacky.

Comment: Hi Martin. As someone who has committed to the CivicRM Q&A site it would be great if you could get your reputation on this site to more than 200 points, as that would really help us move into public beta phase.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the database structure allow this, it seems that there are some code logic that prevents it from working.

So, if you want it to be purely CiviCRM, what you could do is to add all the fields you want in one big profile and then add some html in Field Pre Help / Field Post Help to add the title to separate content. You can then add css and/or javascript to make it look like there are more than one profile.

Comment: This is what I typically do.  user2236575's suggestion of Webform is often the best, but if you want a traditional CiviContribute page, just add all the fields to one or two massive profiles.

Answer (score 1):

A real 'cheapskate' solution is to break up a big profile by eg entering in to the 'help' field of the item above where you want the new profile to begin a horizontal rule and heading such as `<hr><h3>this is my sub-profile title.....`

It can work nicely ;-) and very easy

Answer (score 1):

I think as of 4.4 ( may be 4.3 too ) you can add profile field "Formatting", which is free html content, that can be used as an separator.